# Counting distinct number of records based on a condition in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

```
Item  Location    Empty
    A         X        No
    B         X        No   
    C         X        No
```

The above table is generated by query

```
select it.item,lt.location,lt.isempty 
from locTable lt 
join itemTable it 
on lt.location = it.location
```

Item table has "item" and its "location" information where as
LocTable has "location" and "isEmpty" information

My problem is when i generate a calculated field using the formula

> Sum( CASE [isempty] when 'No' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )

I am getting 3 as the SUM. But as we see from the table there is just 1 location which is "X" and the count should technically be just 1. How can i modify this so that the count is accurate i.e. check whether a location is empty or not and then report as 1 rather than just counting number of "isEmpty = No" from table.

Desired output

[image]
The total slots that are not Empty = 1. This should be the output. Not 3

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? I mean, isn't CNTD enough with a proper use of rows? Do you really need a CF? Maybe I'm not getting your point

Comment: Hi Panto, I need to find out count of distinct locations that have status isEmpty = "No". Right now i am just counting isEmpty = "No" and hence i am getting the answer as 3. (As we see the answer should be 1 as we are just referring to location "X")

Comment: Your formula is to `SUM` over the output of the `CASE`, and your `CASE` outputs the integer 1 for each empty location, regardless of what location it is. Hence, you get a 3 as result for 3 empty locations. The trick is in what you return from the `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this:

[image]

Is this what you need?
If so, there's no need for a CF.

PS: I had to post an answer in order to show you my screenshot

Comment: Hi Panto, Yes but i want this for Each location i,e. "LocationID No 1"

Comment: Could you please provide the desired result in your question just to be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Create a calculated field with

```
If [empty] = 'No'  then
[location] 
End
```

Call it [emptylocation]

Then drag it to your worksheet and choose COUNTD.

So if the location is empty it will populate the calculated field and then count the distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field as below `isempty`:

```
{FIXED Location : COUNTD(EMPTY)}
```

This will eliminate Item from group by and Count distinct happens against Location itself.